# AWS connect instance deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, amazon-connect

Is there a way in which I can revover the AWS instance that got deleted? It had very important data in it. Plus is there any way in which I can know which user has deleted it as multiple users have access to my aws services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not restore deleted instance if no snapshot.

You can use Cloudtrail to check who deleted it